# Is there an easy way to subset all the variables in a regression based on multiple conditions?

Tags: regression, linear-regression

I am trying to analyze [American National Election Studies (ANES)](https://electionstudies.org/data-center/) data from 2020 through linear regressions. Many of the variables (both predictor and outcome) are measured on seven-point Likert scales; however, the variables also contain other numerics to capture responses outside the Likert scales. For example: `-99` meaning `Refused`, `-8` meaning `Don't Know`*,*  `-1` meaning `Inapplicable`, etc.

When I run a regression between two variables—which include all observations (so, even those outside of the Likert scale)—the regressions run fine. For example:

```
lm(df$var2 ~ df$var1)
```

However, I do not want to run regressions with the non-Likert values included. My first novice workaround for this was:

```
lm(df$var2[(df$var2 >= 1) & (df$var2 <= 7)] ~
     df$var1[(df$var1 >= 1) & (df$var1 <= 7)])
```

However, the issue with this solution was that each variable in the regression was a different length.

So, my solution for this was to subset both variables on the same conditions, like below:

```
lm(df$var2[(df$var1 >= 1) &
             (df$var1 <= 7) &
             (df$var2 >= 1) &
             (df$var2 <= 7)] ~
     df$var1[(df$var1 >= 1) &
               (df$var1 <= 7) &
               (df$var2 >= 1) &
               (df$var2 <= 7)])
```

This worked, but it is a very long-winded way of going about this, and as I've tried to move toward including some covariates and fixed effects, things have gotten incredibly complicated. Further, when I try reading what is printed from summary(lm), all the subsets make the entire output intelligible.

Is there an easier/faster/clearer approach for running regressions where certain conditions apply for all the included variables?

Thanks in advance!